# Cannot cast from View to EditText at Android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my xml code..

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

But this line:

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

has an error message.

I don't know what is the problem, and how to solve it.

Comment: Try to clean and build the project... generating new R.java may solve the problem

Comment: You haven't posted enough code. Make sure you have set the contentView properly in your `.class` file where you want to use this `edittext`

Answer (score 0):

*this is you xml code

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edittext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="text"></EditText>
```

*then build the project

*Paste your java code inside onCreat() method

```
EditText edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is occuring in you Activity then remove the
"final" from the EditText.

If your class is fragment then following should work:

Assuming your rootView is defined as below:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_search,
                container, false);
```

where rootView is View that inftates the layout xml file. then you edit text should be declared as below:

```
EditText edittext = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```